# Как удалить повторяющиеся элементы в ArrayList?

Tags: arraylist, java

Есть Arraylist:

```
ArrayList <Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

Хранит разные значения, значения могут повторяться.
Отсортировал методом пузырька:

```
for(int i = list.size() - 1; i >= 0 ; i--)
{
    for(int j = 0 ; j < i ; j++)
    {
        if (list.get(j) > list.get(j + 1))
        {
            temp = list.get(j);
            list.set(j, list.get(j + 1));
            list.set((j + 1), temp);
        }
     }
 }
```

Как удалить дубрирующиеся элементы в ArrayList?

Comment: Самый простой способ сделать Set<Integer> из элементов массива. Конечно, самый неэффективный.

Comment: Ну самое эффективное - сделать все через Tree, но хочется добить этот вариант!

Comment: Через Tree будет еще менее эффективно.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
new HashSet(list)
```

Comment: Можете пояснить, что это означает? То, что мы создаем множество из list. Он удаляет все одинаковые значения, а потом создаем опять ArrayLIst?

Comment: @duddeniska я уже поменял ответ. Первый вариант был сложнее, т.к. я думал, что вам нужно порядок элементов сохранить.

Comment: Спасибо! Первый вариант понял и сделал.