# Удалить из списка все повторяющиеся элементы

Tags: java, list

Задание: Используя динамическую структуру список, сохранить ряд чисел.Удалить элементы, которые повторяются

```
//класс, реализующий список

package q;

public class Link {
int data;
Link next;
Link prev;

public Link(){
data=0;
next = null;
prev = null;
}
public Link(int value){
data = value;
next = null;
prev = null;
}
public void DisplayLink(){
System.out.print(data+" ");
}
}
```

Дана динамическая структура "список". Нужно удалить все элементы, имеющие копию(оставить только уникальные элементы.

```
 //класс, реализующий методы работы со списком
package q;
import java.util.*;
public class DoublyLinkedList {
private static Link first;
private Link last;

public DoublyLinkedList(){
first = null;
last = null;
}

public boolean IsEmpty(){
return first == null;
}
//метод, вставляющий элемент в конец списка
public void InsertLast(int dd){
Link newLink = new Link(dd);
if(IsEmpty())
    first = newLink;
else {last.next = newLink;
newLink.prev = last;
}
last = newLink;
}
//метод удаляющий первое вхождение переменной key
public Link deleteKey(int key){
 Link current = first; 
 while (current.data != key)
 {
 current = current.next;
 if (current == null)
 return null; //такий елемент не знайдений
 }

 if (current == first) //знайдений, перший вузол
 first = current.next; 
 else
 current.prev.next = current.next;
 if (current == last) // останній вузол?
 last = current.prev; 
 else
 // not last
 current.next.prev = current.prev;
 return current; // return value
 }



//метод выводит на экран
public void DisplayForward(){
System.out.print("Список:");
Link current = first;
while(current !=null){
    current.DisplayLink();
    current = current.next;

}
System.out.println("");
}

public static void main(String[]args){
DoublyLinkedList list = new DoublyLinkedList();
Random r = new Random();
int n = r.nextInt(20)+10;
int k=0;
for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
    list.InsertLast(r.nextInt(20)-10);
    k++;}
list.DisplayForward();

System.out.println("Удаляем все лишнее");

list.DisplayForward();
}
}
```

Насколько я понимаю, нужно создать некий логический метод, определяющий есть ли в списке копии элементов, и потом в мейне через цикл пройтись по списку, для каждого элемента вызывая этот метод, и если он вернет true?то использовать метод DeleteKey, удаляющий элемент. Вся проблема в том, что не могу никак додуматься, как написать этот логический метод правильно(а может решение будет другое совсем)

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как удалить повторяющиеся элементы в ArrayList?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/388681/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%83%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b2%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d1%8f%d1%8e%d1%89%d0%b8%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%8f-%d1%8d%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d1%8b-%d0%b2-arraylist)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Преобразуйте свой List в Set. А потом, если нужно, наоборот.

```
Set<Foo> foo = new HashSet<Foo>(myList);
```

Comment: этот вариант не подходит, мне нужно не удалить сами копии,  а и все элементы, у которых эти копии есть, оставив только уникальные элементы @rjhdby

Comment: не совсем вас понял. Дополните вопрос описанием алгоритма, что вы делаете, на каком этапе и что надо дедуплицировать.

Comment: Добавил задание и коментарии к коду. Преобразование в set не подходит, потому что тогда останутся элементы, у которых были копии, а нужно чтоб и этих элементов  не было совсем

Comment: эмм. А вам обязательно писать свой список? Нельзя использовать штатные джавовские?

Comment: увы, нужно именно так, с реализацией собственного списка.
Ради интереса, а если б можно было использовать LinkedList, решение было б очевиднее?

Comment: Стандартный LinkedList отлично преобразуется в Set. Тогда я бы рекомендовал вам реализовывая свой список использованием интерфейса List (implements List<Integer>) и проблема уйдет сама собой

Comment: ладно, буду надеяться, что неправильно понял задание(скорее всего так и есть), спасибо)